# When I add myself "vboxusers" group I an no longer in the "admins" group

Tags: virtualbox, users

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and I installed VirtualBox.

This required me to add myself to the `vboxusers` group but when I add myself to `vboxusers` group I am no longer be in other groups and especially `admins` group!

When I add myself back to `admins` group I no longer be am in the `vboxusers` group !

Commands that I used

- to add user to "vboxusers": `usermod -G vboxusers myusername`
- to add user back to admins group in single user mod: `usermod -aG admin myusername`

Comment: @Caesium Thank u. Thanks all :) Solved by following Caesium's solution :D

Comment: Then you should fix the accepted answer, currently a non-working solution is accepted which will confuse future visitors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your second command is right.

By default, `usermod -G` replaces all supplementary groups the user is in (the primary group is generally named the same as your username, and specified separately; don't mess with that though). By also using `-a` it appends the groups you give.

So this should work (and does, for me, just tried it):

```
usermod -aG vboxusers myusername
```

If running that command takes you out of any other group then you've found a bug. Note you have to relogin to see the effects.

Comment: i am getting error: `usermod: group 'vboxusers' does not exist`

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively:

```
gpasswd --add myusername vboxusers
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [`usermod man page`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/usermod.8.html) the correct command to add a user to a group is

```
sudo usermod -G group -a username
```

or in your case since you want to add your self to the `vboxusers` group that will be

```
sudo usermod -G vboxusers -a $USER
```

Comment: Exactly equivalent to `-aG group` (assuming usermod knows how to parse args)

Answer (score 1):

Never use the top method to add a user to `vboxusers` by using the `usermod -G vboxusers myusername` command. This will make you lose your sudo privileges!

If you have lost your sudo privileges, you can use the [method described here](http://forum.ubuntu.org.cn/viewtopic.php?t=392060&p=2899449) to recover them. It boils down to executing the following command:

```
usermod -G adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,plugdev,lpadmin,guoshicheng,vboxusers myusername
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The question's author already used the command you're telling him not to use. He has also already accepted a solution for his problem. There is actually no point in anwering the question again. And linking to a site in Chinese is also not very helpful on an English site.

Comment: @bender Actually there is a point if the answer is valid and on topic. Accepting answer means that it worked for the OP. Please read the [about page](http://askubuntu.com/about).

Comment: @Symin: Nevertheless, the question's author **already used this command**. Strictly seen, this is already not an answer to the question. The accepted answer already describes in detail what has been done wrong and why, this answer adds (almost) no new information. And describing (once again) how to get back lost privileges has been done many many many times on this site. And just for the sake of completeness, this command won't work any more after sudo privileges were lost (unless one hasn't logged off yet or still has an open root shell).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is just open the terminal and `vi /etc/group` then add of replace `vboxusers:x:128:uname` (uname of the account), save and log out. Just login and open VirtualBox, Settings -> USB -> Add filter from device. I think it will work.

Answer (score -1):

To add a user to multiple groups use the following command is executed with commas seperating each group for example: admin,vboxusers

useradd -G admin,vboxusers myusername

Comment: That will add a new user and make the user belong **only** to those groups.

Comment: If that's so, then Oli's answer is wrong too?